# plone.app.linkintegrity not working if absolute_url doesn't match path?

Tags: plone, archetypes

- Plone 4.1.6
- plone.app.linkintegrity 1.4.5

I'm not getting a link integrity warning when deleting content, despite that option being turned on in Editing CP, which I was able to trace back to where plone.app.linkintegrity should be creating an "isReferencing" reference in the reference_catalog. It was not being created, which causes link integrity to not catch anything.

Despite using "link using UID", plone.app.linkintegrity.modifiedArchetype is using field.getAccessor(obj) instead of field.getRaw(obj), so the links are already transformed and are presented here as full, resolved URLs. Whether that's appropriate is for another topic - this is just to point out that will try to find the object by identifying the portal root in the URL path and then traversing from there.

My url is something like http://myurl.com/portals/maryland/page-two and the portal path is /maryland. Note the extra "/portals" component to the url path that does not correspond to any Zope object. This appears to be the crux of the problem.

When plone.app.linkintegrity.handlers.findObject is called, the value of "base" is something like "<ATDocument at /maryland/page-two>" and the value of "path" is "/portals/maryland/page-one". "portal_path" uses the Zope physical path though, and gets "/maryland/". So "path" does not startwith "portal_path" and so it will first try to traverse to "portals", which doesn't exist, and it will return None object.

I believe the line

```
portal_path = '/'.join(obj.getPhysicalPath()) + '/'
```

Should instead be

```
portal_path = urlsplit(obj.absolute_url()).path + '/'
```

This seems to work for me. The reference is created and link integrity works. I am hesitant to report this as a bug since I am not sure my assumptions are correct. Also that line is still in there on the latest github release and I am doubting such a bug could persist for so long. If someone could check my sanity by confirming that this looks like a bug, or pointing out an error on my part, that would be appreciated.

snippet of Apache config:

```
RewriteRule ^/portals(/.*|$) http://myinternal_ur.com:9507/VirtualHostBase/https/%{HTTP_HOST}:443/VirtualHostRoot/_vh_portals/$1 [proxy,last]
```

Comment: This questions would be probably better answered at http://community.plone.org/

Comment: Probably worth a bug report with a PR and your fix. As far as I understand your use-case, that should be the fix.